# Odoo Warning - The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions

Tags: python, odoo-9

When a POS user logins and try to access his allowed POS session, a warning is displayed:

```
The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator. (Document type: pos.config, Operation: read)
```

Why is it so? How to rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the user does not have sufficient permissions (in Settings > Users). The user must be at least a member of the Point of Sale "User" group in order to have read permissions for `pos.config`.

[image: User Permissions Screenshot]

If the user is a member of this group, then there may be a further issue with the group itself. In that case, you should enable Developer Settings, then go to Settings > Groups > Point of Sale / User and ensure they have the Access Right highlighted below.

[image: Group Access Rights Screenshot]

[More about Odoo security](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/security.html)

Comment: The user is a member of the Point of Sale "User" group and have the Access Rights as stated above too. But the warning is shown.

Answer (score 0):

About solution of your question I can suggest you one way that in **Settiogs >>Users >>"Your_User_Name"** in that go to "Point of Sale" tab. In that you have to set your session name. By this way for particular user you can set particular session and you get access right.